# Get access to MVC partial page in angular js directive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to access a mvc partial page in angular custom directive, code as shown below, but no luck. I took this solution from the link - [ASP.NET MVC Partial View in an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633863/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-in-an-angularjs-directive) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
(function (baseApp) {    
    var myDirective = function (DATA_URLS, $compile, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var ddd = $http.get(DATA_URLS.ROOT_PATH + "Views/Shared/specialView1").success(function (data) {
                    element.html(data);
                });
            }
        };
    };
    baseApp.directive('baseMyDirective', ["DATA_URLS", "$compile", "$http", myDirective ]);

}(angular.module('baseApp')));
```

Comment: what did you get if you type in browser address "DATA_URLS.ROOT_PATH + "Views/Shared/specialView1 with proper DATA_URLS.ROOT_PATH ?

Comment: Well, it says the resource can not be found. The DATA_URLS.ROOT_PATH just points to https://localhost/myapp... I just tried accessing other pages in the same folder as my partial view in the browser, but for all of them, it says, the resource cant be found

Comment: so specialView1 in angular view or MVC partial view ?

Comment: so path should be rather localhost:[port]/Views/Shared/specialView1

Comment: Where can i find the port info and how do i use that in angular. Any idea.

Comment: if you debuging on local host you've got 'http://localhost:65324/... so 65324 is number of port

Comment: Well, i am not getting any such URL with port no, its just localhost/myapplicationname/views...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57504/discussion-between-sylwester-and-whyato8).

Comment: Thanks a lot sylwester, as discussed in chat, I was able to retrieve the page by calling controller/action. If you would like to post it as an answer, please do that, I would like to accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use controller/action path in get call

```
(function (baseApp) {    
    var myDirective = function (DATA_URLS, $compile, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var ddd = $http.get(DATA_URLS.ROOT_PATH + "controller/action").success(function (data) {
                    element.html(data);
                });
            }
        };
    };
    baseApp.directive('baseMyDirective', ["DATA_URLS", "$compile", "$http", myDirective ]);

}(angular.module('baseApp')));
```